# Script stops, although "set -e" was set afterward read

Tags: bash, githooks

I have a script for a git post-receive hook

```
read oldrev newrev refname
set -e

echo DELETE
rm -rf *
echo DELETED
...
```

When I run the script, the ouput looks like this

```
remote: DELETE
```

But then the script stops. But when I remove the "set -e" or remove the "read" it works.

```
read oldrev newrev refname

echo DELETE
rm -rf *
echo DELETED
...
```

results to

```
remote: DELETE
remote: DELETED
```

**or**

```
set -e

echo DELETE
rm -rf *
echo DELETED
```

results to

```
remote: DELETE
remote: DELETED
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

**Edit**: Add output of the second and third code example

Comment: By "works", you mean files are removed and `DELETED` is output?

Comment: Yes, for the second and third code example the whole script runs.

Comment: Unless this is something really specific to Git hooks, I can't reproduce it with a simple example. I don't see how the `read` command could cause the later `rm` command to fail (which is the only thing that could explain your three results).

Comment: By the way, this is one more reason not to use `set -e` in the first place.

Comment: How else do you prevent the script from continuing when an error occurs?

Comment: Test for an error explicitly using `if `